# Converse of L'hopital's Rule

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f, g : [1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)/g(x) = 1$ and $f(x) \to \infty$. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the following conclusion to hold
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = 1.
$$
At first I thought the problem might be easier but I now think it actually isn't. I tried rewriting the above limit as double limit and exchanging the limits but couldn't get so far. Any suggestions as to how to approach this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: What if we also assume that $f'$ and $g'$ are nonnegative functions that tend to 0 as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: I'm not sure if there *are* any nice necessary and sufficient conditions, other than just the conclusion itself.  As a counterexample to think about, try $f(x) = x + \sin(x^2)$, $g(x) = x$.

Comment: There are maybe some nice sufficient conditions, such as $f$ and $g$ both polynomials, or similarly $f$ and $g$ both rational functions.